# UITapGestureRecognizer has no member tag

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

In this case i need my uiLabel clickable, so i add uiTapRecognizer. Then, i need to send the indexpath section to the tag so i can get the choosen section.

But when i try to  get the sender.tag in tapFunction() there is error : UITapGestureRecognizer has no member tag

If i change the sender to uiButton ->  func tapFunction(_ sender:uiButton) {
it doesn't print anything inside the function

Is there any workaround for this case (still using uilabel not change it to uibutton)?

Can i also send data when #selector tapfunciton(_: , data:"text")
and read it in tapFunction(data:String)? If this possible, can someone show it ?

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoanCell", for: indexPath) as? LoanCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let item = viewModel.itemsForRowAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapFunction(_:)))
                cell.syaratLabel.tag = indexPath.section
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.syaratLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
                 return cell
             }
    
 @objc
    func tapFunction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("successprint")
        let item = viewModel.itemsForRowAt(indexPath: IndexPath(row: 0, section: sender.tag))
       
        let viewController = DetilSandKViewController(messageSnK:item.prdAgreementDetail, titleSnK:item.nomorKontrak)
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Get the tapped view, and read its tag? Something like: `let tappedView = sender.view; let viewTag = tappedView?.tag`

Comment: Or have the tapGestureRecognizer target some other object instead of self, like item?